# Trail renderer collision detection in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I added the "Tail Renderer" component to the 2d object. Now I want to detect when the other object interacts with it make notification for this event. I have googled so much but the solutions that I have found were not good for the performance. So, the length of the trail is dynamic that is why making the collider for every vertex point of "Tail Renderer" is making slow the game. Isn't there any alternative way of doing it? Maybe another way not with "Tail Renderer". Actually, does not matter, I need just good performance.

Comment: You could use a constant amout of box colliders and move/scale/rotate them to approximate the trail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity 2D Trail Renderer Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531677/unity-2d-trail-renderer-collision)